# how to pipe wc -l output to echo output

Tags: bash, shell

I count errors in a log file by doing `grep error logfile | wc -l`

It outputs 10

I want to print `Error count found in logfile is 10`

I think need to pipe it thru echo but how can I append 10 to echo output?

I tried

```
 var="$(grep -i error logfile | wc -l)" | echo "Error count found in logfile is $var"
```

Comment: var="$(grep -i error * | wc -l)" && echo "Error count found in logfile is $var"

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should not pipe the var into echo, but instead run them in sequence:

```
var="$(grep -i error * | wc -l)"
echo "Error count found in logfile is $var"
```

or you can define the variable just for the echo command, by doing with *bash*:

```
 var="$(grep -i error * | wc -l)" ; echo "Error count found in logfile is $var"
```

---

As said in the comments below, of course you can embed your command call in your echo statement:

```
echo "Error count found in logfile is $(grep -i error * | wc -l)"
```

Comment: Looks like I need && before echo

Comment: ah sorry, that's a zsh thing, I'm amending… I've been spoiled by many years using a greater shell 

Comment: What's the difference between the `bash` and the `zsh` solution?

Comment: The difference is that in zsh you can set the env in the same line of the call, making that var only available for the callee, not spoiling the environment afterwards (I guess it should be possible with bash as well with some obscure `set` option)

Comment: In other words if you do `X=42 echo $X` you can't use `$X` on the next line. If you do `X=42; echo $X`, then you can!

Comment: @zmo In what version of `zsh` does `foo=3; foo=5 echo $foo` print 5 and not 3? Pre-command environment assignments work in any POSIX shell, but do not affect parameter expansions in the command line.

Comment: (Which is not to say that `zsh` isn't great; it is :) It just isn't different from `bash` in this regard, if I understand correctly.)

Comment: I might have a weird `set` environment setup. But I don't really want to check `zshall(1)` to know which one  though, it's not a question of it being POSIX, just being a Bourne descent.

Comment: Unless previously declared, `$var` becomes a shell-global variable in _both_ cases. The only difference between your two snippets is a _formal_ one: 2 lines vs. 1. Something like `v=1 echo "$v"` doesn't work in _any_ POSIX-like shell, from what I can tell. Yes, the `v` definition becomes an environment variable for the command invoked, but `$v` is handled by a shell expansion up front, before the environment variable is ever seen. `v=1 eval 'echo "$v"'` would work, but that's obviously ill-advised (and using `echo "$(echo 1)"` will do).

Comment: Just embed it in the string like @mklement0 's answer. The extra $var does nothing but make it more verbose and harder to read, IMHO.

Comment: @mort updated for thoroughness. Though, my answer was about fixing his line.

Answer (score 4):

To **simply embed the (stdout) output from a command in a string**, without the need to also store that output in a variable, simply **use a command substitution (`$(...)`) inside a double-quoted string (`"..."`)**:

```
echo "Error count found in logfile is $(grep error logfile | wc -l)"
```

As pointed out in [Inian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41728215/45375), `grep` supports counting matches directly, via its `-c` option, so the above can be simplified to:

```
echo "Error count found in logfile is $(grep -c error logfile)"
```

Using a *variable* to store `grep`'s output is only needed if you need to refer to it again later:

```
var=$(grep -c error logfile)
echo "Error count found in logfile is $var"
# ... use $var again as needed
```

---

As for what you've tried: `echo` only accepts command-line *arguments*, not stdin input, so using a pipeline (`... | echo ...`) is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 2):

Use `printf` and `grep` with `-c` flag for pattern count.

```
printf "Error count found in logfile is %s\n" "$(grep -chi error logfile)"
```

The flags used in `GNU grep`

```
-c, --count
       Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching lines for each input file.  
       With the -v, --invert-match option  (see  below),  count  non-matching lines.

-h, --no-filename
       Suppress the prefixing of file names on output.  This is the default when there is 
       only one file (or only standard input) to search.

-i, --ignore-case
          Ignore case distinctions in both the PATTERN and the input files.
```

Comment: this answer is wrong, as it will give the number of errors for each file, not a compounded count.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `grep -c`. `printf` is not required here since you can simply put the command substitution into the message like echo "foo $(command)".

Comment: @zmo Please elaborate

Comment: if you run the command you'll get `Error count found in logfile is log1.txt:0\nlog2.txt:2\nlog3.txt:4\n` etc… not `Error count found in logfile is 10`

Comment: @zmo: OP has mentioned in a single file

Comment: he did not mention a single file, he said the command with `logfile`, but also does it with `grep *`

Comment: @zmo: Shouldn't that be clarified with OP before down voting? If he wants to print a custom string like that he wouldn't select multiple files? makes sense?

Comment: That could be a *useful use of cat* :) .. `echo "nerrors: $(cat * | grep -c error)"`

Comment: if the OP says it's ok with one file, I'll un-downvote, I promise! and @hek2mgl love that ☺

Comment: I edited post to clear confusion. Though @zmo thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @user2384694: Hope you find the answer useful

Comment: Splitting the OP's single `logfile` argument into 2 arguments `log` and `file` is confusing; it introduces noise in the form of  needing `-h`; similarly, introducing `-i` is a distraction. While learning about `-c` is helpful, it is ultimately incidental to the solution. In the case at hand, in the context of `bash`, `printf` offers no advantage over using `echo` with an embedded command substitution.

Comment: @mklement0 : fixed the spacing, auto-correct screwed it up!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some more examples of different ways to handle this task, just to help you get a feel for bash's features and options:

`(echo -en "Error count found in logfile is "; grep error logfile | wc -l)`

`{ printf "Error count found in logfile is " && wc -l < <(grep error logfile); }`

`printf 'Error count found in logfile is %d\n' $(grep -c error logfile)`

`awk '/error/{++c} END{printf "Error count found in logfile is %d\n", c}' logfile`

`var=$(grep -c error logfile); echo "Error count found in logfile is $var"`

If you want to go out of your way to use a "here string":

`cat<<<"Error count found in logfile is $(grep -c error logfile)"`

Also, here's a bash builtin only option:

```
declare -i c=0
while read l; do
  [[ $l == *error* ]] && ((++c))
done < logfile
echo "Error count found in logfile is $c"`
```

Comment: I like the awk version, in which I would drop `printf` and directly say `print "blabla", c`.

Comment: @fedorqui Good point. I was so caught up in bash printf syntax that I forgot about print

Answer (score -1):

Use apostrophes.

```
var=`cat x.dat | grep error | wc -l`
echo $var
```

Comment: `\`` is not an apostrophe (single quote), but technically a _grave accent_ (`U+0060`), commonly known as a _backtick_ (_back tick_). `\`...\`` is the _legacy_ syntax for command substitutions, whereas the modern syntax is `$(...)`, as used by the OP.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I need to evolve here :-)

Answer (score -1):

`echo "Error count found in logfile is "$(grep error logfile | wc -l)`

Comment: There is no need for a second command substitution with `echo` - the inner one is sufficient. Also, it is generally more robust to embed the command substitution in the double-quoted string.

Comment: You're already echoing the string, so he's right, inner echo is redundant and wastes a subshell.

Comment: Please try to provide context with your answer.  A standalone answer may solve a problem in this specific scenario, but an explanation may solve many future problems.  Try to include what you think is causing the issue and why your answer will solve it.

Comment: I don't know what to say.  The reason for the error has been explained in the previous answer's comment, so I don't want to repeat that.  The other comments provided answers to the error in 2 statements.  I tried to help and provided an integrated single statement, and I got down voted, that's very encouraging to newbies.